# How to delete a clone when touched

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I am working on a program that will create a bunch of clones, and it will delete a clone when the clone is taped on. I only want it to delete the clone that is taped on. I am having an issue with the touch event listener. It says that I am trying to index a nil variable, but I defined it earlier in the program.

I have tried changing the variable to be a global variable.

```
display.setDefault("background", 0, 0, 200)
math.randomseed(os.time())

local boat = display.newImage( "boatt.png" )
boat.x = 163
boat.y = 225

local score = 0
local spawnCnt = 0
local spawnTable = {}
local startTime = os.time()
local startTime2 = os.time()
local fish_tapped


local function spawn ()
    local obj = display.newImageRect("fishpic.png",70,70)
    obj.x = math.random(1, 300)
    obj.y = (0 - math.random(30, 400))
    obj.isDone = false
    -- Note: Second argument is function name without brakets
    obj:addEventListener("touch", touched()) --i added brackets to this
    return obj
end

local function onSpawn ()
spawnCnt = spawnCnt + 1
spawnTable[spawnCnt] = spawn()
end

local function movement (event)
-- SPAWN OBJECT USING TIMER
if os.time() - startTime >= 1 then 
onSpawn()
startTime = os.time()
end



-- MOVE OBJECT
if spawnCnt > 0 then
for i = 1, spawnCnt do 
if spawnTable[i].isDone == false then 
if spawnTable[i].y > 600 or spawnTable[i].fish_tapped == true then
spawnTable[i].y = 700
spawnTable[i].isDone = true
display.remove(self)
self = nil
else 
spawnTable[i].y = spawnTable[i].y + 4
end
end
end
end 
end

Runtime:addEventListener ("enterFrame",movement)



--when i tried to have touched() in the event listener for touch it said that i was calling a 
--nill value, so I made the funciton global. 
function touched( event )
    local obj = event.target
    obj.fish_tapped = true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (not tested)

```
local function movement (event)
  ...
  -- Replace 
  -- if spawnTable[i].y > 600 or fish_tapped == true then
  -- with
  if spawnTable[i].y > 600 or spawnTable[i].fish_tapped == true then
  ...
end

local function touched( event )
    local obj = event.target
    obj.fish_tapped = true
end

local function spawn ()
    local obj = display.newImageRect("fishpic.png",70,70)
    obj.x = math.random(1, 300)
    obj.y = (0 - math.random(30, 400))
    obj.isDone = false
    -- Note: Second argument is function name without brakets
    obj:addEventListener("touch", touched) 
    return obj
end
```

Read more:

- [Scope for Beginners](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/basics/scope/index.html)
- [Tap/Touch Anatomy](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/events/tapTouchAnatomy/index.html)

Comment: I was wondering what the local obj = event.target does in this code. I tried the code and it now has no errors, but it does not register when I click on the object. Also, I was wondering why you have to put obj. in the fish_tapped = true. Why does it need to be obj.fish_tapped instead of just fish_tapped?

Comment: `event.target` indicate clicked object on the screen. Since you used `obj` name for new fish object I use the same name. However the `obj` object in `spawn` and `touched` functions are different objects because they are local variables for those functions. This means they don't exist outside those functions. The name `fish_tapped` indicate that it should be attached to individual fish object. That way you can check whether fish was tapped. This impliy more changes in code (I updated code above).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented the new changes and it still has errors. I corrected a couple of small errors and I commented the changes that I made. I added brackets to touched() in the touch event listener. I also made touched() a global variable. The error I am encountering now is that it says I am trying to index local "event" which it says is a nil value. It then says that the error occurs in the touched function, the spawn, and onspawn function and on the line in the movement function in which I call onspawn. It also says: "? in function <?:190>". I am not sure why this error is here

Comment: The second argument of `obj:addEventListener()` is function name i.e. `touched`. That is why I removed brackets from your code.